# Почему не работает относительный import в Python (PyCharm)?

Tags: python, pycharm

Есть следующая архитектура проекта:

[image: Архитектура проекта]

Проблема заключается в неисправности относительного импорта. Т.е. в теории все должно работать, как надо, но что-то идет не так.

В файле **main**.py я пишу from . import sieves.py. Т.е. делаю относительный импорт.
Так же в файле test_1.py я тоже импортирую этот файл и пишу from .. import sieves.py.
PyCharm не ругается и не подчеркивает это, как ошибку, но при запуске я получаю это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это очень странно, ведь я указал рабочую директорию и даже проверил ее через os.getcwd(). Я видел такую же проблему на нашем всеми любимом портале, и там было решение указать именно рабочую директорию. Но мне это не помогло.

Заранее благодарю за ответы!

Comment: a в __main__.py пробовали писать import sieves?

Comment: @Константин да, это действительно работает. Хоть PyCharm и подчеркивает это как ошибку, это работает... Но проблему не решает. Я не могу пользоваться относительным импортом =(

Comment: Имейте в виду, что относительные импорты основаны на имени текущего модуля. Так как имя главного модуля всегда "__main__", модули, которые должны использоваться как главный модуль приложения, должны всегда использовать абсолютные импорты. [Proof оф. документация] (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references)

Comment: @SergBocharov я, может, не совсем вас понял.. Я переименовал файл __main__ на main, но проблема так и осталась...

Comment: что у тебя в __init__.py или он пустой?

Comment: @Yakov все init'ы пустые, а это как-то влияет?

Comment: пакет это ведь папка с init.py внутри, насколько я понимаю (.) для таких штук нужна, у вас ведь не так.

Comment: Относительный импорт работает от директории указанной как `sources root`, т.е. в `example.py` вы можете указать импорты относительно главной директории проекта, такие как `from . import sieves`  или  `from .tests import test1`.  В вашем случае вам нужно использовать в `main.py` `import sieves`, в `test_1.py` соответственно: `from tests import sieves` - это и будут относительные пути для них внутри пакета

Comment: @SergBocharov нет, к сожалению, ничего из этого не работает... Я подозреваю, что что-то не так с PyCharm, а точнее с моими настройками конфигурации. А вот что именно...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я со всем разобрался! Оказывается, я не так понимал импорт в Python.

1. Дело в том, что когда мы запускаем какой-либо файл, для Python нет ничего выше этого ЗАПУЩЕННОГО файла. Т.е. запущенный файл является корнем, и мы не сможем при импорте подняться выше него, даже если там будут какие-то другие модули/пакеты. Мы можем импортировать в ЗАПУЩЕННЫЙ файл (у которого `__name__ == "__main__"`) только пакеты и модули, находящиеся на одном уровне с ним или ниже.
2. `__main__.py` делает ПАКЕТ, в котором он лежит, ЗАПУСКАЕМЫМ. Поэтому у меня не работала команда python `__main__.py`. Нужно в таком случае использовать `python -m package`, где `-m` говорит, что надо запустить как модуль.
3. Использовать main.py в самом корне каталога удобно тем, что у нас никогда ничего не будет выше этого файла. Значит, мы не запутаемся при импорте и всегда будем импортировать только то, что рядом с файлом и что ниже его по уровню. Еще раз: `__main__.py` лишь делает ПАКЕТ запускаемым.

Надеюсь, кому-то поможет :)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте просто `import sieves`, интерпретатор по идее должен рассматировать директорию package как main директорию проекта, при наличии `__main__` в ней

Comment: Это действительно работает, но проблема с относительным импортом остается.